# What type of rollover menus does Apple use in their Contacts App?

Tags: xcode6, osx-mavericks, contacts, nspopupbutton

Does anyone know how Apple creates their rollover menus in the Contacts "business card" view*? I am trying to replicate that interface in an App I'm writing, but I'm not sure how to get there via XCode. I'm currently running Mavericks...

Thank you in advance!

* i.e. the "work" heading for an address is a context-sensitive popup menu that allows you to copy the address, open in maps, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to replicate the Contacts interface exactly (I suspect they are doing some custom drawing routines), but I came up with something that was good enough for me. I created pulldown buttons with the "gradient" style, and visual set to "bordered".

Here is the key: during startup, I call the following:

```
[myButton setShowsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside:true];
```

When you hover over the button, it highlights. Click, and the menu drops down. Perfect!